# When toggle divs why the input values stays

Tags: reactjs

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   inputvalue : '',
      allval: '',
      bool: false
  }
 }
  
  onChangeOfInput =(name,value) =>{
   this.setState({
   [name]: value
  });
  }
  
  clickHandler = () =>{
   console.log(this.state);
      this.setState({
        bool: !this.state.bool
      });
  }

 render() {
  return (
   <div className="hello">
       {this.state.bool 
       ? <div>1:<Input placeholder="Title 1" name="Title1" onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} />
      2:<Input placeholder="Title 2" name="Title2"  onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} /> </div>
        :
        <div>
    3:<Input placeholder="Title 3" name="Title3"  onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
    4:<Input placeholder="Title 4" name="Title4"  onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
        </div>
        }
        
     <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Change</button>
   </div>
      
  )
 }
}

class Input extends React.Component  { 
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   inputvalue: ''
  }
 }

 handleChange(e) {
  
  this.setState({
   inputvalue: e.target.value
  });
    this.props.onChangeOfInput(this.props.name,e.target.value)
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
    value={this.state.inputvalue} 
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    />
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

When I enter some values then I toggle the `DIVs` by clicking the `Change` button. The input values stays on the field. How to make sure the input value field only shows its own value? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using state in child component i.e `Input` component. You can add state in your parent component i.e `App` component for each input field.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputvalue : '',
      allval: '',
      bool: false,
      Title1: '',
      Title2: '',
      Title3: '',
      Title4: ''
    }
}
```

After that you can map each input field value with a specific state of `App` component by passing `value` props to `Input` component.

i.e.`<Input placeholder="Title 1" name="Title1" value={this.state.Title1} onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} />`

So you can update render method by adding `value` props in each `Input` component

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div className="hello">
       {this.state.bool 
       ? <div>1:<Input placeholder="Title 1" name="Title1" value={this.state.Title1} onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} />
                2:<Input placeholder="Title 2" name="Title2"  value={this.state.Title2} onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput} /> </div>
        :
        <div>
                3:<Input placeholder="Title 3" name="Title3" value={this.state.Title3} onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
                4:<Input placeholder="Title 4" name="Title4" value={this.state.Title4} onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput}/>
        </div>
        }

            <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Change</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
```

And at last you can use the `value` props in `Input` component

```
<input 
     type="text" 
     placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
     value={this.props.value} 
     onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

So update your `Input` component

```
 class Input extends React.Component  {

        handleChange(e) {
        this.props.onChangeOfInput(this.props.name,e.target.value)
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
                    value={this.props.value} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    />
            )
        }
    }
```

In this way you can make sure the input value field only shows its own value

Answer (score 1):

You should `map` an array of values, in your case `[1, 2]` and `[3, 4]` to the corresponding `Inputs`.

They will then be considered unique by giving them a `key`.

I also change your change function to the following : `onChangeOfInput = index => value =>`.

This allows us to preset your function and not require any `name`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inputvalue: '',
            allval: '',
            bool: true
        }
    }

    onChangeOfInput = index => value => {
        this.setState({
            [index]: value
        });
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            bool: !this.state.bool
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hello">
                {(this.state.bool ? [1, 2] : [3, 4]).map(index =>
                    <div key={index}>
                        {index} : <Input placeholder={'Title ' + index} onChangeOfInput={this.onChangeOfInput(index)} />
                    </div>
                )}
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Change</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inputvalue: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            inputvalue: e.target.value
        });
        this.props.onChangeOfInput(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                value={this.state.inputvalue}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```